# Identify Font File Used in Microsoft Word 2010

Tags: fonts, ms-word

I know that the font files used by Microsoft Word is located at

> C:\Windows\Fonts

I am particularly concern about the font `OCR A Std`. I want to locate the font files for the `OCR A Std` `regular` font, `bold` font, `italic` font and `bold italic` font. Below are the sample fonts:

> [image]
>
> Regular
>
> [image]
>
> Bold
>
> [image]
>
> Italics
>
> [image]
>
> Bold Italics

Now, I want to locate the four corresponding font files for the said font. But when, I look at `C:\Windows\Fonts`, only `2` font file with the name `OCRAStd.otf (OCR A Std Regular)`and `OCRAEXT.TTF (OCR A Extended)` is found. Unlike with other fonts like `Times New Roman`,its corresponding four font versions are found, namely: `Times New Roman Regular`, `Times New Roman Bold`, `Times New Roman Italics` and `Times New Roman Bold Italics`. My questions are :

1. Is `C:\Windows\Fonts`, the right location where I can find the font files for `Microsoft Word 2010`? If no, then where? If yes, what are the font file names corresponding to the four versions of `OCR A`? How can I determine it by myself?
2. If it is not  in my computer, where can I download it? I already searched the web but only found `OCR-A Std Regular` and `Bold`, no `Italics` and `Bold Italics`.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. This is an end-user issue and needs to be asked on a site such as Super User - it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no files for OCR-A Std Italic or Bold Italic. These are what is known as [*synthesized fonts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-fonts). They are:

> [...] supplied in regular and bold styles only, meaning italic characters are synthesized by slanting the upright styles.

This happens for many fonts, not just OCR-A (please review the linked article for other examples).

Comment: So it means that Microsoft Word just slants the upright styles to achieve that italic look. How can I do it in Python? Rendering a slanted font? Anyways, that is another question. Thank you.

Comment: It's actually the Windows operating system itself that performs the slanting, and yes, how to do it in Python is another question. Please ask separately and be sure to detail which image/font-drawing package you are using.